# PHP nesting duplicates into its own object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

The output below is a result of a MySQL query. Some companies have multiple locations and location numbers. Instead of it creating a new "Company" array each time I want all the locations for that company to be nested under the first company array.

So in essence there would be another object under the company array containing another location/number.

My brain is letting me down. Anyone care to help?

```
<?php

$json = '[
{
    "Company 1": [
        {
            "location": "Location Name 1",
            "number": "0001"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Company 1": [
        {
            "location": "Location Name 2",
            "number": "00045"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Company 2": [
        {
            "location": "Location Name 1",
            "number": "00021"
        }
    ]
}
]';

$x = json_decode($json);
var_dump($x)
?>
```

Comment: Please add your sql query as well. This should be solved by altering the query, and not with php. You could obtain this by using GROUP BY

Comment: @OleHaugset It's a shitty query. See: https://kopy.io/O557f#l5XK4YvyljOws4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by iterating the array and storing data in a new array:

```
$x = json_decode($json, true);
$x2 = array();
foreach($x as $k => $v)
{
    foreach($v as $k2 => $v2)
    {
        $x2[$k2][] = $v2[0];
    }
}
print_r($x2);
```

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [Company 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [location] => Location Name 1
                    [number] => 0001
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [location] => Location Name 2
                    [number] => 00045
                )

        )

    [Company 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [location] => Location Name 1
                    [number] => 00021
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with one line using array_merge_recursive function:

```
$arr = array_merge_recursive(...json_decode($json, True));
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/933685)